# Palindrome algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, palindrome

I had an interview yesterday where I had to write an algorithm on the whiteboard for working out if a value is a Palindrome in C#. The pressure got to me a bit but I've written my version of it in Visual Studio this evening.

```
 private bool Ispalindrome(string args)
        {
            var index = 0;
            var reverseArray = args.ToCharArray();

            do
            {
                if(index == args.Length)
                    return true;

                index++;
                var startingChars = args.Substring(0, index);
                var stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();

                for (var i = 0; i < index; i++)
                {
                    stringbuilder.Append(reverseArray[reverseArray.Length-i-1]);
                }

                if (startingChars != stringbuilder.ToString())
                    _isPalindrone = false;

            } while (_isPalindrone);
            return _isPalindrone;
        }
```

Doe anyone have any recommendations on how to make this more efficient?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just reverse the string, then check if they're equal?

Comment: @TZHX My only reason for not using reverse is that in the interview it was prohibited and I've tried to write it without using .Reverse() as well.

Comment: Ah, yes... got to love arbitrary restrictions. Well, if I were tasked with that, I'd consider that your solution approaches N^2 operations for a palindrome (scaling quite badly with size of the string). I can [suggest](https://gist.github.com/mikejwhitty/5dee879e6910e0189fe9246221e10dc4) a way it might be done only looping through the input once, but it's been a long day and I don't have the energy to check for edge cases.

Answer (score 6):

You are making it harder than it needs to be.

You just need to compare one character at a time:

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return false;
    char[] chars = s.ToLower().ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length / 2; i++)
        if (chars[i] != chars[chars.Length - 1 - i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Or:

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return false;
    char[] chars = s.ToLower().ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0, j = chars.Length - 1 ; i < j; i++, j--)
        if (chars[i] != chars[j])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: +1, but I think you should return `true` rather than `false` for the empty string. Also, `i <= chars.Length / 2` can safely be changed to `i < chars.Length / 2`. (That will also let you eliminate the specific check for the empty string.)

Comment: You don't actually even need to call `.ToCharArray()`. Strings are naturally indexable in C#.

Answer (score 2):

How about this in pseudocode:

```
front = 0
back = str.len() - 1
isPalindrome = true;
while (front < back) {
   If str[front] != str[back] {
     isPalindrome = false;
     break;
   }
   ++front;
   --back;
}
return isPalindrome
```

This doesn't need a new structure, and only access at most \$n+1\$ characters on the string, so it's \$O(n)\$. This would probably work for most Latin character sets. Two character symbols would throw this off track.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that for the majority of strings, the first character is not the same as the last character. And the string is *not* a palindrome for that reason. I'd expect an algorithm that runs in constant time for most strings. And in linear time for strings that *are* palindromes.

It would also be nice to handle Unicode correctly. At the very least strings with four byte characters need to be handled correctly. But *really* strings containing characters with modifiers, and such characters in non-canonical form, should be handled correctly as well.